# Unknown type name sqlite3 error

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I am new to iPhone and working on Xcode to connect with SQLite, when I am declaring `sqlite3` it throws the "Unknown type name sqlite3" error. My code is as follows:

```
#import "DBManager.h"
static DBManager *sharedInstance = nil;
static sqlite3 *database = nil;
static sqlite3_stmt *statement = nil;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two related errors:

> Unknown type name 'sqlite3'

And:

> Use of undeclared identifier 'sqlite3'

If you receive either of those for SQLite references, you can import `sqlite3.h` to resolve them:

```
#import <sqlite3.h>
```

---

If you neglect to link to the `libsqlite3.0.dylib` under your target's "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" settings, you may also receive errors like so:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_sqlite3_open", referenced from:
      -[ViewController openDatabase] in ViewController.o
  "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
      -[ViewController closeDatabase] in ViewController.o
```

If you receive errors like that, then you can go to your "Target" settings and add `libsqlite3.0.dylib` to the list of "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" (see [Project Editor Help: Linking to a library or framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html)).